# MikroORM repository throwing Global Context error when debugging in Visual Studio Code

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, mikro-orm

I am trying to use MikroORM repositories, but I keep getting the Global Context validation error when I use them while debugging in Visual Studio Code.  I am using the RequestContext middleware, just as the documentation and demo applications suggest.  The error does not occur when I run the application in a terminal window instead of by debugging.

I am currently running Visual Studio Code version 1.68.1 on Windows 10, using Node version 18.2.0.

Error Recreation:

1. Install the sample application Express + MongoDB + JavaScript from the Mikro-orm Example integrations (https://github.com/mikro-orm/express-js-example-app).
2. Follow the instructions in the README.md to run the application.
3. Use Postman (or equivalent) to create an author.

   3.1. POST http://localhost:3000/author\

   3.2. Body (raw/JSON):

   ```
    {
        "name": "test person",
        "email": "test@test.com",
        "age": 42
    }
   ```
4. Use Postman (or equivalent) to retrieve authors.

   ```
    4.1. GET http://localhost:3000/author
   ```
5. Copy the id of the author you just created.
6. Use Postman (or equivalent) to update the author.

   6.1. PUT http://localhost:3000/author/<id from step 5.>

   6.2. Body (raw/JSON):

   ```
    {
        "name": "test 'success' person"     
    }
   ```

**NOTE:** This will succeed, proving that everything is configured correctly.  I have tried this with both the repository's version of Mikro-orm as well as the current latest version (5.2.3).

7. Stop the application (Ctrl-C in terminal)
8. Attach the debugger

   8.1. Open the file app\server.js

   8.2. Open VS Code's Run and Debug panel.

   8.3. Click the "Run and Debug" button.
9. Use Postman (or equivalent) to update the author.

   9.1. PUT http://localhost:3000/author/<id from step 5.>

   9.2. Body (raw/JSON):

   ```
    {
        "name": "test 'failure' person"     
    }
   ```

This time the update will fail with the message:

> "Using global EntityManager instance methods for context specific
> actions is disallowed. If you need to work with the global instance's
> identity map, use `allowGlobalContext` configuration option or
> `fork()` instead."

Within the sample application, the error occurs in author.controller.js, within the router.put('/:id', async (req, res) section, specifically on the line await DI.authorRepository.flush() (line 55). However, experimentation suggests that the error will occur the second time you make any repository call.  For example, if you duplicate the findOneOrFail line like this:

```
const author = await DI.authorRepository.findOneOrFail(req.params.id);
const foo = await DI.authorRepository.findOneOrFail(req.params.id);
```

the error will occur on the second call to .findOneOrFail.

The error is being thrown in @mikro-orm/core/EntityManager.js, in the getContext method (line 737).  When the second call to the repository occurs, getContext is called multiple times.  The first time has the following call stack

```
EntityRepository.flush
MongoEntityRepository.em (get)
EntityManager.getContext
```

This call is successful.

However, the second call to getContext fails.  It has this call stack:

```
EntityRepository.flush
EntityManager.flush
EntityManager.getUnitOfWork
EntityManager.getContext
```

The issue seems to be that between the two calls to getContext, em._id goes from not 1 to 1.  It looks to me like the EntityManager with an _id of 1 is the global context we shouldn't be using.  However, when you run the code without debugging, em._id is not 1 during any of these calls.

I have not been able to figure out why the context is not retrieving the correct entity manager when in debugging mode.

Comment: It's not about "em._id goes from not 1 to 1", generally speaking you will either use a fork (so `_id > 1` and `em.getContext()` is a no-op, just returns `this`), or you use the global EM (e.g. from DI container), where the `em.getContext()` call will get resolved to the contextual fork. If you are not inside the correct async context, `em.getContext()` will give you `this` again, resulting in the global EM.

Comment: In other words, the async context (created via `AsyncLocalStorage`) gets broken, and `em.getContext()` gives you only the global EM (if called on global EM).

Comment: Thanks, Martin.  AsyncLocalStorage breaking would certainly explain the issue.

I tried reverting to Node 16.16.0 and the issue went away.  I also tried upgrading to the latest node (18.6.0), but the bug still occurs. Hopefully they fix this version of Node soon.  For now, I'll look into using Node v.16.

Comment: @SeanBueckert any updates on this? Did you fix it on Node 18?

Comment: I did not.  As Node 16 is currently recommended for most users, I reverted to that verseion and carried on.  Hopefully the issue with Node 18 is resolved before I need to upgrade.